# Faster way to append ordered frequencies of pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a list of the number of elements in each group in a pandas series. In my dataframe i have column called ID, and all values occur multiple times. I want to make a list containing the frequency of each element in the order by which they occur.

So an example of the column ID is `[1,2,3,3,3,2,1,5,2,3,1,2,4,3]`

this should produce `[3,4,5,1,1]` since the group-ID 1 occurs 3 times, the group-ID 2 occurs 4 times etc. I have made a code that does this perfectly:

```
group_list = df.ID.unique().tolist()
group_size = []

for i in group_list:
    group_size.append(df.ID.value_counts()[i])
```

The problem is that it takes way to long to finish. I have 5 million rows, and i let it run for 50 minutes, and it still didn't finish! I tried running it for the first 30-50 rows and it works as intended.

To me it would be logical to simply use `value_counts(sort=False)` but it doesn't give me the group-ID frequencies in the order they occur in my series. I also tried implementing extend because i read it should be faster, but I get a `"numpy.int64 object is not iterable"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a Series

```
ser = pd.Series([1,2,3,3,3,2,1,5,2,3,1,2,4,3])
```

You can do the following:

```
ser.value_counts().reindex(ser.unique()).tolist()
Out: [3, 4, 5, 1, 1]
```

Reindex will reorder the value_counts items based on the order they appear.

Comment: That was a really efficient solution, it took less than a second! I haven't used or heard about the reindex function before, but it seems very useful. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. In general, loops should be avoided when using pandas but the real problem in your code was you were calling `df.ID.value_counts()` in each iteration of the loop again and again. If you had saved that to a variable, that could have saved you some time too.

Comment: Ah of course! That was a silly mistake. I tried to avoid looping by using value_counts but i did not know how to correct the order of the output.